How to style depending on the br and span tag hierarchy within a p
I have a span a br in the same position within a p. I want that if the br is before the span the span has a different styling, but if the span comes after the br the span has another styling.
p:first-child span {
  margin-top: 2px;
  color: green
}


p:first-child span + br {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: red
}

p > br {
  display: none;
}

<div>
  <p>
    <br/>
    <span>Lorem</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <br/>
  </p>
</div>


jsfiddle
The first Lorem is to be red and the second Lorem is to be green
It's an array that contains different data and some have tags like this. So it's not something I can just rip off

p:first-child span is wrong, the span or br would be the first child not the paragraph

if br and span are the only elements then consider :last-child and :first-child


p span:first-child {
  margin-top: 2px;
  color: green
}

p span:last-child {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: red
}

p > br {
  display: none;
}
<div>
  <p>
    <br>
    <span>Lorem</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <br>
  </p>
</div>




I was really stupid in the attempt hahaha You nailed it!
